# Populate form selections lists depending on previous answers drop down

Tags: jquery, html

I really don't know where to begin with this and can't seem to find the right terms to find the answer on the net to help me achieve this.

I want to create a form with drop down selection lists that will then display a set of drop down answers based on the previous drop down selection.

For example your first drop down would be: Fruit or vegetable, fruit selected so next option would apples or oranges, apples selected so your next option would be granny smith or cox.

How do I go about doing this jQuery? any help much appreciated?

Comment: I think you should start [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23346371/how-to-change-dropdown-options-based-on-another-dropdown-selection-values-retri) and if stuck then come back.

Answer (score 0):

You can use onchange function to trigger this: 
For example:

```
<select id="selectBox1">
<option value="fruit">Fruit</option>
<option value="Vegetable">Vegetable</option>
</select>

<select id="resultBox1"></select>
```

in jquery:

```
$("#selectBox1").change(function(){
var value = $(this).val();
if(value == 'fruit'){
// append or display your fruit list
}else{
//vegetable list
}

});
```

Hope this will help you out..

Comment: Many thanks, if I have more than two options, would this work? would I keep using elsif? instead of else?

Comment: yes it will work, if you have more than 2 option then use $.each function to read one by one and display ...

Comment: having some issues getting this working, where does "resultbox1" fit in with the jquery , when I select fruit nothing is displayed?